# Stream and download video but block direct access?

Tags: .htaccess, video, download, streaming, block

I found in a streaming site the thing I want to do and I already lost 2 days to understand how they do it. So please analyze the next info and tell me how he does this thing???

Example of what I mean is in this link: http://www.animeforce.org/ds.php?file=AbsoluteDuo/AbsoluteDuo_Ep_01_SUB_ITA.mp4

In development kit we found the direct link of this video: http://www.lacumpa.org/DDL/ANIME/AbsoluteDuo/AbsoluteDuo_Ep_01_SUB_ITA.mp4

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative;" class="html5video lightsoff" id="wtf">
<div class="main-container" id="wtf">
<div class="hero-unit">
<video controls="" preload="metadata" id="video-player">
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.lacumpa.org/DDL/ANIME/AbsoluteDuo/AbsoluteDuo_Ep_01_SUB_ITA.mp4"></source>
</video>
</div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight: bold;" class="lightsoffbtn"><a href="#">Modalità Cinema!</a></div></div>
```

The second was if you use Download button in the page you access to adfly "they use it to monetize" after skip the adds download start like from a hotlink but if you copy the link from where you download is the same from embedded sourcecode and if you try after stop download to use again direct link, again you are redirected to "Anty Hotlink".

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be a HTTP_REFERER block. If the request for the content does not include the URL of the correct referring page, in it's HTTP HEADER, you block access eg. Using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}    !www.somsite.com/some_URI_path 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|gif|png)$   -                 [F,L]
```

Beyond that you can do things with cookies, e.g again with mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}    xxxxxxxxxxxx  [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|gif|png)$   -                 [F,L]
```

Or if you want to get serious use session based blocks.

Comment: This code I mast place in web site hatchess our server?

Comment: Incidentally, `jpg|gif|png` will not address `mp4` files in the original question.